How to enable AWS SNS TOPIC AND SUBSCRIPTION request on my server as it is only accessible with particular IP
We had a server iin which under virtual host we had allowed only one IP address, so situation is
we are sending emails using ses, and bounced email is pushed to SNS topics and topic is subscribed fro HTTPS to push response from aws to our configured server, but server is not accepting request due to virtual configuration of allowing server for particular IP.
we are trying to recieve request from AWS SNS BOUNCE TOPIC it is pushing result to our server but due to configuration of certain IP, it is not allowing AWS to push request to the server.
Please help us to fix this situation as AWS not able to push request to our server and throwing error:
client denied by server configuration:
proxy:http://www.*********.com/webhooks/service/ses
we had listmonk in the server.
Recieve Request from AWS to our server

You can use Lambda with your SNS Topic and configure your function to run inside a specific Private Subnet/VPC that uses a NAT Gateway with a fixed IP for all outbound connections.

VPC Documentation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html
NAT Gateway Documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html

Let me know if you have any doubts
